# Reactjs And .Net API, send formdata and others parameter

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, backend, multipartform-data

I have a problem that has been going on for over a month now, I've tried everything I know about react and .net core, so I thank anyone who helps me. I need to send a formdata and other parameters to the api as a foreign key, but I can't find a viable solution.

here is my .net action to insert data

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AdicionarCandidato([FromForm]AddCandidatoDTO candidato,  Guid classe, Guid curso, Guid ano, Guid periodo)
        {
            try
            {
                // candidato.DescricaoFoto = Upload(candidato.FileFoto).ToString();               
                await _inscricao.Adicionar(candidato, classe, curso, ano, periodo);
                await _inscricao.Persistir();
                
                return Created();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Erro ao inserir candidato: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

next the react redux funtion to send data

```
export const insertInscrito = async (dispatch, candidato, classe, curso, ano, perido) => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.reqInsertInscrito());
    
    try {
        // api request
        const { data } = await axios.post(baseUrl, candidato +classe +curso +ano +perido)
        dispatch(actionCreators.insertInscrito(data));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(actionCreators.errorInsertInscrito(error.message));
    }
}
```

then the form page with inputs and  methods

```
const handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('Nome', selectedCandidato.Nome);
      formData.append('Sobrenome', selectedCandidato.Sobrenome);
      formData.append('NomePai', selectedCandidato.NomePai);
      formData.append('NomeMae', selectedCandidato.NomeMae);
      formData.append('DataNascimento', selectedCandidato.DataNascimento);
      formData.append('Rupe', selectedCandidato.Rupe);
      formData.append('NumeroBilhete', selectedCandidato.NumeroBilhete);
      //formData.append('TextoFoto', selectedCandidato.TextoFoto);

      formData.append('Sexo', selectedCandidato.Sexo);
      formData.append('EstadoCivil', selectedCandidato.EstadoCivil);
      formData.append('Email', selectedCandidato.Email);
      formData.append('Telefone', selectedCandidato.Telefone);
      formData.append('Provincia', selectedCandidato.Provincia);
      formData.append('Municipio', selectedCandidato.Municipio);
      formData.append('Rua', selectedCandidato.Rua);

      insertInscrito(dispatch, formData 
        + selectedCandidato.ClasseId 
        + selectedCandidato.CursoId
        + selectedCandidato.AnoLectivoId
        + selectedCandidato.PeriodoId)

  }
```

First I tried to change the formdata to normal text and then I tried to transform each parameter as an element of the formdata, but the api still does not recognize the other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install `npm i axios` and then

send requests using the package as below

```
  const axios=require('axios');
    
    const submitForm=async ()=>
    {
      const {data}=await axios({
          withCredentials: true,
          url:'your endpoint will be here',
          method:'post',
          data: selectedCandidato,
          headers:{
             Authorization:'api token'
          }
    }).then(response=>{
         return response;
    }).catch(error=>{
         return error;
    });
     
     console.log('request sent -> ',data);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help bro, but i already resolve the issue, i only had to remove the parameter on the api and then create some variables as form properties.